# Plotting graphs with C++

Tags: c++, matlab, plot

I am writing program in c++ to numerically solve differential equations (ODEs and PDEs). The reason being simple - c++ is much faster than matlab for large scale computation. However matlab is clearly winner when it comes to plotting. Is there any way I can get matlab like plotting in c++?

Comment: i would just google it

Comment: Which GUI toolkit are you targeting?

Comment: You have a few options here. You can find some c++ libraries. Or you can export the results to something else to plot. Just remember that you can always export the data after you solve a problem and then plot the data with a different tool.

Comment: What's about putting your cpp code into a mex function and use Matlab?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to code the solver in C++ and call it from Matlab using mex files.

For more information:

- [Introducing MEX-Files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html)
- [MEX-File Creation API](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-mex-files-1.html)

Comment: +1, I used a similar way during the benchmark and prototype phases of my thesis.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it is quite hard to write `C++` numerical software that beats a well written `MATLAB` code. The latter is by default multi-threaded, uses latest Intel MKL optimizations (which, unless you pay for the Intel compiler, you won't be able to use).

With respect to plots, you can probably use `gnuplot`, http://www.gnuplot.info/links.html

Answer (score 1):

To add to the list of options, you could always write the C++ application to produce some matlab readable output, for example a CSV file.

QWT has some plotting widgets for free, but it is dependant on Qt GUI. The commercial version of Qt has a lot of different plotting functionalities as well. See https://qt-project.org and http://qwt.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

I faced this difficulty when i had to plot some graphs for my C++ project. There are many workarounds, for instance gnuplot and created csv file which can be opened using Excel.

If you are using Visual Studio, I would recommend my method, which is to install Qt-add in for Visual Studio and use QWT. The configurations can be a little tad tricky, but I be willing to guide you along, just simply drop a comment if there is any difficulties.

QWT can be used in real time applications too, for instance, a live histogram for a video, where the histogram will be automatically updated without the need to refresh or call it. Call it once and its sufficient. (: